# Setting up eclipse for Pig

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, eclipse-plugin, apache-pig

I am trying to setup my eclipse (Mars) to write some Pig UDF. I downloaded 4 different JAR's but still I am having issues.

Following are the 4 JAR's which I added as External library.

1. pig-0.8.3.jar
2. pig-0.14.0.jar
3. pig.0.11.1.jar
4. piggybank-0.11.0.jar

I am trying to write a Pig UDF for Decode. Can anyone point me, where am I going wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error is eclipse giving you?

Comment: @MikePone 2 errors: 1. Description Resource Path Location Type The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.apache.commons.logging.Log. Fix the build path then try building this project PigDecode Unknown Java Problem 2. Description Resource Path Location Type The type org.apache.commons.logging.Log cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files DecodeUDF.java /PigDecode/src line 1 Java Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> Cannot find the class file for org.apache.commons.logging.Log

You need to add commons logging jar file.  Probably a bunch of others too.  You will want to consider using maven.  It automatically downloads the dependencies it needs.

Comment: that helped.. just added `org-apache-commons-logging.jar` thanks @Mike